# Program execution terminates in Code Blocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have written a program to measure execution time of quick sort and am using Code Blocks to compile and run it. When I input random set of numbers my program runs well for any size of data. But when I try to input ascending/descending sorted set of numbers, my program terminates for large data set (>35000) saying program stopped working.

This same code runs well on linux. But on linux I am not able to measure time using QueryPerformanceCounter(). So I have to use Code Blocks on windows.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<windows.h>
double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if(!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
    printf("QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\n");

    PCFreq = (double)li.QuadPart;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}
double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return (double)(li.QuadPart-CounterStart)/PCFreq;
}
int part(int a[],int low,int high)
{
    int pivot,i,j,temp;
    pivot=low;
    i=low+1;
    j=high;
    while(i<=j)
    {
        while(a[i]<=a[pivot])
            i++;
        while(a[j]>a[pivot])
            j--;
        if(i<j)
        {
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[j];
            a[j]=temp;
        }
    }
    temp=a[j];
    a[j]=a[pivot];
    a[pivot]=temp;
    return j;
}
void QuickSort(int a[],int first,int last)
{
    int q;
    if(first<last)
    {
        q=part(a,first,last);
        QuickSort(a,first,q-1);
        QuickSort(a,q+1,last);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,a[100000],i;
    printf("Enter the size of array:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        //a[i]=rand()%100000;   //average case (random data)
        a[i]=i;                 //ascending sorted input
        //a[i]=n-1-i;           //descending sorted input
    /*
    printf("The UNsorted array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    */

    StartCounter();
    QuickSort(a,0,n-1);
    printf("Sorting time %lf micro seconds\n",GetCounter()*1000000.0);

    /*
    printf("\nThe sorted array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    */
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting following error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I use `clock(3)` (sufficient resolution for a quick test) on Linux it works up to and including the fixed limit of `100000`. To avoid that fixed limit I used `malloc()` to reserve the memory dynamically in the following sketch (doesn't make a difference in the outcome, I just wanted to put it on the heap instead of the stack)

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    // ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!
int main()
{
    int n,*a,i;
    clock_t start, stop;
    printf("Enter the size of array:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        //a[i]=rand()%100000;   //average case (random data)
        a[i]=i;                 //ascending sorted input
        //a[i]=n-1-i;           //descending sorted input
    /*
    printf("The UNsorted array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    */

    start = clock();
    QuickSort(a,0,n-1);
    stop = clock();
    printf("Sorting time %f seconds\n", (double)(stop- start)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    /*
    printf("\nThe sorted array is:\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%d ",a[i]);
    printf("\n");
    */
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Ascending array entries: 11 seconds for 100,000 entries and for a million…a segfaulta at

```
QuickSort (a=0x7ffff7ee3010, first=174677, last=199999)
```

(repeatable)
I think the recursion is just a wee bit too deep (stack size here: 8 megs which goes accord for 180,00 calls with two ints and a pointer and some overhead).

So: nothing actually wrong here.

**EDIT**
To show that it is indeed the stack lets increase it:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
    // ALL CHECKS OMMITTED!
int main()
{
  int n, *a, i;
  clock_t start, stop;
  // 256 MB
  const rlim_t bigger_stack = 256L * 1024L * 1024L;
  struct rlimit rlim;
  int ret_set, ret_get;

  ret_get = getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlim);
  fprintf(stderr, "get %d %d %d\n", ret_get, (int) rlim.rlim_max,
      (int) bigger_stack);
  if (ret_get == 0) {
    if (rlim.rlim_cur < bigger_stack) {
      rlim.rlim_cur = bigger_stack;
      ret_set = setrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, &rlim);
      if (ret_set != 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "getrlimit %d, setrlimit %d\n", ret_get, ret_set);
      }
    }
  }



  printf("Enter the size of array:");
  scanf("%d", &n);
  a = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    //a[i]=rand()%100000;   //average case (random data)
    a[i] = i;           //ascending sorted input
  //a[i]=n-1-i;           //descending sorted input
  /*
   * printf("The UNsorted array is:\n");
   * for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   * printf("%d ",a[i]);
   * printf("\n\n");
   */

  start = clock();
  QuickSort(a, 0, n - 1);
  stop = clock();
  printf("Sorting time %f seconds\n", (double) (stop - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  /*
   * printf("\nThe sorted array is:\n");
   * for(i=0;i<n;i++)
   * printf("%d ",a[i]);
   * printf("\n");
   */
  free(a);
  return 0;
}
```

Checked with 200,000 elements: works in ca. 47 seconds.

Comment: Are we not suppose to type-cast the value returned by malloc() to the type of pointer variable??

Comment: I tried to explicitly allocate the memory using malloc/calloc but still facing the same issue. The above code is not working with Code Blocks on windows.

Comment: No, we are not supposed to cat the output of `malloc()` just the opposite. Also: the heap (allocated with `malloc()`) is not the problem, the stack is (too many recursions). What does "is not working " mean exactly? I mean: what errors from the compiler/linker/OS etc. Please copy&paste the errors, don't paraphrase. I think the `getrlimit()` et al. have different names in Windows but that was just for proving the point that the stack (too many recursions) is the culprit. CodeBlock offers its own method to increase the stack, see e.g.: http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?topic=7556.0

Comment: If I do not tye cast the return value of malloc() it gives an error message saying "error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'int*' "

Comment: Post the code that generates the error. The comment makes no sense. (`void`) is a generic pointer and can be cast to/from any other type (that's kind or the purpose....). No, you don't cast the return of `malloc` (or `calloc`, etc..) See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation.

Comment: @NaitikParekh you are most probably using a C++ compiler, please check and switch to a C compiler if you want to write C code. The differences are small but significant.